# After editing a post in the first posts queue, I am switched to the suggested edits queue

Tags: bug, review

I was reviewing some first posts, and I decided to fix a typo in one of them.

This post had one suggested edit in the queue, so editing it brought up the edit review page. The edit didn't fix the typo, so I went to improve it.

After I fixed the typo, I found myself at the next item of the **suggested edits** review queue, rather than back among the first posts.

I think that you ought to stay in the queue you were browsing in such a situation, and be able to complete your original review.

Comment: `I think that you ought to stay in the queue that you're browsing in such a situation.` -- Why?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because the user is getting moved from one context(the first post review) to  another(suggested edit review queue).  this is unexpected behavior for the user.

Comment: Oh, I see.  That is weird.